# Trying to crack the guessing server

Tags: python

I have a small request. I have an assigment in my school in which I need to connect through nc to server and then guess the number in order to find the secret message. I have the source code of this server and I've been trying to crack this for the last week. If you could just point me in the right direction that would be great.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import os, sys
import ast
import random

def write(msg):
  sys.stdout.write(msg)
  sys.stdout.flush()

def read(prompt=''):
  if prompt:
    write(prompt)
  return sys.stdin.readline().strip()

def loop():
  RANGE = 1000000
  num = read('Select a number (0, 10000000000000000000000): ')
  try:
    num = ast.literal_eval(num) + 0
    assert 0 < num < 10000000000000000000000
  except:
    write("Oops! Wrong number!\n\n")
    return
  rand = num + int(random.random()*RANGE)
  guess = read('Guess a number in range: [{:n}, {:n}]: '.format(num, num+RANGE))
  try:
    guess = ast.literal_eval(guess)
  except:
    write("Oops! You probably didn't enter a number!\n\n")
    return
  if guess == rand:
    write('Wow! The secret is [...].\n')
    sys.exit(0)
  write('Better luck next time!\n\n')  

def main():
  write('Hello there in "Guess the number!"\nYou have 30 seconds.\n')
  while True:
    loop()

main()
```

Comment: Repeat the same number all over.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Doesn't `loop()` create a new number every time user fails?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala loop() creates new number in every execution.

Comment: With "cracking" you mean you only are allowed to use the program in the designated way?

Comment: @syntonym I can do whatever I want with it but the secret message is stored on a server so that's the only limitation.

Comment: Is your assignment to write this program, or just to use it?  If your assignment is to use it, you're sunk--the program is badly broken.

Comment: @WayneConrad my assignment is to find potential vulnerability in this code so that I can make this statement "guess == rand" true or find other way in.

Comment: With this program as presented, your only chance is social engineering, or just lots of tries and sheer luck.  In any case, this isn't a question about programming that is appropriate for SO.  If the program were sane, it might be a question for the _programmers_ site ("what's the algorithm for most efficiently guessing the number"), but as written, it has no hope.

Comment: @WayneConrad Thank you very much for your help. I will try different way.

Comment: You have 30 seconds and 1 in 1000000 chance. Write a script that dumps `'1\n'` 4 million times in there.

Comment: There is a flaw. It says "_you have 30 seconds_", but there is no time limit in reality.

Comment: I think there is a security flaw if you insert a floating number.

Comment: I was thinking it could dump a traceback somehow but it doesn't

Comment: @AnttiHaapala What 4 millions of '0/n' could possibly change?

Comment: Another possibility is that assert is turned *off*

Comment: @MrLemon You have a 999999/1000000 chance to guess right. If you guess oft enough you will get it right.

Comment: @syntonym I kind of doubt it because I've tried even very big ones.

Comment: Since there is no time limit you can "try" millions of times with a script or something (i m not familiar with netcat).

Comment: @syntonym Doesn't the fact that the number is generated randomly every time I send the wrong one affect the whole possibility of brute forcing?

Comment: @user5061 Yes it is possible, but every time I send the wrong one the new one is generated so that makes it possibly impossible.

Comment: @MrLemon No, it's not impossible. Every time you have 999999/100000 to fail the guess. After 1000000 times (math involved but trust me) you have about 63% chance to guess it right. Despite the fact it changes every time.

Comment: @user5061 Ok, I will try it. Long night ahead of me :) Thanks for help.

Comment: @MrLemon What you need to do is create a script that will send constantly numbers. Eventually you will get it. You can actually send the same number over and over again. It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is the `ast.literal_eval`. It allows for floating point numbers to be entered. The floating point numbers have a precision of <16 digits. By entering `0.999999999999999e22` you make the end result after summation also `0.999999999999999e22`, thus you can enter it twice to get in.

Example session:

```
Hello there in "Guess the number!"
You have 30 seconds.
Select a number in range (0, 10000000000000000000000): 0.999999999999999e22
Now guess a number in range: [1e+22, 1e+22]: 0.999999999999999e22
Wow! The secret is [...].
```

The reason is that

```
>>> 0.999999999999999e22 + 1000000 == 0.999999999999999e+22
True
```

However surprisingly it might fail with `0.9e22`, though it wouldn't take *too* much time with that:

```
>>> 0.9e22 + 999999 == 0.9e22
False
```

Comment: you need to enter it for both the low range and the guess

Comment: Argh, you beat me to it! Note that you can also use 0.9e22, which is a bit.. "nicer"? Also the author only asked for hints, but I wouldn't know what kind of hints to give him.

Comment: It is my belief that questions and answers on Stackoverflow should be about general usefulness and knowledge and not about hinting to one person.

Comment: Ah and 0.9e22 is not enough, it can still get rounded up sometimes

Comment: Even if I hint in the correct direction it might not be enough, this is not at all obvious to someone who does not know floating point by heart. This could be bruteforceable too, though it seems that sometimes the waited number takes some more time to pop up

Comment: Ah indeed after some testing I believe it is not possible to always brute force in 30 seconds.